# how to deal with anonymous variables in your dataset to get better predication

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

i have data-set where i am having 4 anonymous variables as shown below and also target variable is kind of anonymous:

[image]

can someone please tell me how to deal with anonymous feature in machine learning ,what is best approach for feature engineering from this anonymous variables , how i can improve my predication from this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do multiple steps :

1- scale the numeric features and one-hot encode the categorical ones (you can also encode your categorical variables with their number of appearances = replace each value with it's count)

2- study correlation between your target and other variables

3- Use different plots to know your data better

4- Use variable selection methods while modeling